# Add the same calculated property to every Symfony2 Controller in bundle

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig

I'm converting an application over from a legacy framework to Symfony2. One of the things the app has is a tiny little message in the bottom corner of the rendered page that says

```
served by appserver3 in 200ms
```

or similar. It changes depending on the appserver you're on and the amount of time it took to serve the request. The value for the appserver is set in a config file (but that's largely irrelevant here).

Should I create a `BaseController` type class that extends `Controller` and then have all my controllers extend that? If so, how would I go about making sure that the `BaseController` always adds the `responseTime` and `appServerName` to the list of variables that will be passed to my twig template without having to add it manually in every controller like this:

```
// e.g. src/MyNamespace/MyBundle/Controller/AboutUsController.php
return $this->render('MyNamespaceMyBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('var1' => $var1, 'appServerName' => $this->getAppServerName(), 'responseTime' => $this->getResponseTime()));
```

(Obviously this would assume that I created the `getAppServerName` and `getResponseTime` methods in my `BaseController`.)

This seems like a lot of copypasta and my whole reason for moving to Symfony2 is to avoid that :\

Comment: Why not get rid of this message? Not really a message every user want to read ^^

Comment: I think that's pretty irrelevant to the question. The message doesn't really matter, but the general technique for achieving this is what I'm really interested in.

Comment: If you want some code to be included in all template files, you should put it in the twig file on the top of your template hierarchy. Many times this is app/Resources/views/base.thml.twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

For dynamic parts in the templates, especially in the base templates which are extended from every template, you can render the output from a controller action. It's like twigs `include` but it includes the dynamic content returned.

See [Embedding Controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) in the documentation.

Outputting the served appserver is easy. Simply get the parameter from container. Calculating the load time may be a more complicated task and not really necessary for the user.

## Solution 2

If it's only a static `appserver` parameter configured in your `parameters.yml` you can define it as a twig global variable in your `config.yml`:

```
twig:
     globals:
         appserver: "%appserver%"
```

Now you can include it in the needed twig template:

```
serverd from {{ appserver }}
```